# linking old account to new phone for pewdiepies tuber simulator

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

How do I get my old tuber simulator account on my new phone? I don't have access to my old device!
I've tried everything I can think of! How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have access to your google play/game center account?

Try connecting it.

If not I don't know.

Comment: I edited it. Did that help?